# Is there a way to get an array of ticked checkboxes from a form using the GET method? PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox, get

I am trying to get an array of all ticked values from the GET form in php. Currently the value that is returned by doing `$_GET['cat']` is the last value ticked as a string.

```
<form method='get' action='/products.php'>
  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat' value='Spirits' class='mr-1'>Spirits
  </p>

  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat' value='Liqueurs' class='mr-1'>Liqueurs
  </p>

  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat' value='Wine' class='mr-1'>Wine
  </p>
</form>
```

I have found many solutions for this using a POST form, but I am trying to do it with a GET form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can try like this:

```
<form method='get' action='/products.php'>
  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat[]' value='Spirits' class='mr-1'>Spirits
  </p>

  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat[]' value='Liqueurs' class='mr-1'>Liqueurs
  </p>

  <p class='rob-font my-0'>
     <input type='checkbox' name='cat[]' value='Wine' class='mr-1'>Wine
  </p>
</form>
```

This will give an array of all values you ticked on